# Graphite: No Average Data

Tags: graphite

and sorry, the following question is probably easy to answer, but I'm just stuck.

I have been querying a value at 5-minute intervals for a year, which I now want to export from Graphite to a CSV file.

http://192.168.1.1/graphite/render/?target=summarize(icinga2.XXXMON1.services.www_XXX_de_-_Besucher_online.check_user_xxx.perfdata.Besucher.value, '5min', 'total')&from=20200101&format=csv

The output looks like this:

```
2021-01-19 15:00:00,7961.666666666667
2021-01-19 15:05:00,
2021-01-19 15:10:00,
2021-01-19 15:15:00,7635.0
2021-01-19 15:20:00,
2021-01-19 15:25:00,
2021-01-19 15:30:00,7447.333333333333
2021-01-19 15:35:00,
2021-01-19 15:40:00,
2021-01-19 15:45:00,7446.0
2021-01-19 15:50:00,
2021-01-19 15:55:00,
2021-01-19 16:00:00,
```

What function can I use to have the values output to me in 5minute increments? If I limit the query time to one day, I get the desired data:

```
2021-01-19 15:00:00,8032.0
2021-01-19 15:05:00,8032.0
2021-01-19 15:10:00,7821.0
2021-01-19 15:15:00,7821.0
2021-01-19 15:20:00,7542.0
2021-01-19 15:25:00,7542.0
2021-01-19 15:30:00,7448.0
2021-01-19 15:35:00,7448.0
2021-01-19 15:40:00,7446.0
2021-01-19 15:45:00,7446.0
2021-01-19 15:50:00,7581.0
2021-01-19 15:55:00,7581.0
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Can you rephrase you subject and question to be more explicit ? The first dataset is indeed in 5min increments. Is it the lack of value in some datetime the issue ? In addition, can you post the url for the second dataset ? And finally, maybe I'm mistaken, but in the [Render Function documentation about summerize](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/stable/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.summarize) I don't see a `total` aggregation functions. The aggregation functions should be `average, median, sum, min, max, diff, stddev, count, range, multiply & last.`